# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

While running the application of spring-boot, I'm having the following error. I don't find any reason for that error to appear. Please help me figure this out.

**stack trace**

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener$CloseContextOnFailureApplicationListener does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract getOrder()I of interface org.springframework.core.Ordered.
    at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.findOrder(OrderComparator.java:142)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.findOrder(AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.java:65)
    at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.getOrder(OrderComparator.java:125)
    at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.getOrder(OrderComparator.java:113)
    at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.doCompare(OrderComparator.java:82)
    at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.compare(OrderComparator.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:360)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1515)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1749)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.asUnmodifiableOrderedSet(SpringApplication.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getListeners(SpringApplication.java:1234)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.contextLoaded(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.contextLoaded(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:394)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:328)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:118)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

There's no error in the code or in my `gradle` dependencies while running the project but it still throws the error.

**Gradle File**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'docker'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

buildscript {
project.ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'
    jarName = 'search'
    versionName = '1.0.0'
    gradleDockerVersion = '1.2'
    swagger2version = '2.9.2'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-    plugin:${project.springBootVersion}"
    classpath "se.transmode.gradle:gradle-    docker:${project.gradleDockerVersion}"
}
}

task createWrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = '5.5.1'
}


group = 'com.techno.homes.search'
mainClassName = 'com.techno.homes.search.Application'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8


repositories {
mavenCentral()
jcenter()
}

ext {
springCloudVersion = 'Greenwich.SR2'
}

dependencyManagement {
imports {
    mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-    dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
}
}

dependencies {
// compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.0.4.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: '2.0.4.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.hibernate.validator', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.0.16.Final'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web-services', version: '2.0.4.RELEASE'
compile group: 'ma.glasnost.orika', name: 'orika-core', version: '1.4.6'
compile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-library', version: '1.3'
compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-test-autoconfigure', version: '2.0.4.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '5.1.8.RELEASE'
compile(group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '5.4.3.Final')
compile(group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.17.Final')
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-test'
compile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.15.0'
compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '1.2.4'
compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-core', version: '1.2.4'
compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '1.2.4'
compile group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', name: 'jsr305', version: '2.0.1'
compile group: 'com.spotify', name: 'docker-maven-plugin', version: '1.2.0'
compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.8'
runtime group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.46'
testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test'
testCompile group: 'com.github.tomakehurst', name: 'wiremock',     version: '1.58'
testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-spring', version: '1.2.5'


// Basic Spring boot with config client
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config')
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")

// Spring OAuth2 security
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
// compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2")
compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-core')
// compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt")

// Eureka client
//  compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka')
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
// Zipkin tracing
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin')
// Swagger for API testing
compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:${swagger2version}")
compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:${swagger2version}")
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-core'
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config'
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-web'
// compile group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth', name: 'spring-security-oauth2'
//can't define without version
compile group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth', name: 'spring-security-oauth2', version: '2.3.6.RELEASE'


//jsckson
compile group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-mapper-asl', version: '1.9.13'

//camel
compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-spring-boot', version: '2.15.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-pulsar', version: '2.24.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-core', version: '2.24.1'

//elastic search
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch'
compile group: 'net.java.dev.jna', name: 'jna'
compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'transport'
compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.plugin', name: 'transport-netty4-    client'

// JAX-B dependencies for JDK 9+
implementation "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.11"
implementation "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.2.11"
implementation "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.11"
implementation "javax.activation:activation:1.1.1"

//json
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-json'
compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20190722'

//to fetch external api
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.9.3'

}
```

**Main Class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.techno.homes.search"})

public class SearchApplication {
private static final Logger log = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(SearchApplication.class);

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    SpringApplication.run(SearchApplication.class, args);
    Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").build();
    Client client=new Config().client();
    System.out.println(client.toString());

} 

}
```